# Does Spring Data Couchbase reactive support pagination?

Tags: reactive-programming, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I have use-case to provide an api which returns list of users. As there are more than 10000 users so there is a need for pagination as well.
As I am using Spring data couchbase reactive I am not able to find a way to implement pagination in a reactive way for my api.

Is it possible to achieve pagination by which api callers can control how many number of records they want and they can process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the standard N1QL LIMIT and OFFSET:

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} where #{#n1ql.filter} and companyId = $1 LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3")
Flux<Users> listUsers(String companyId, Integer limit, Integer offset);
```

Comment: Can I pass "*" as company id as I need all companies data in a paginated response?

Comment: companyId is just an example of some random attribute. You can simply remove it.

Comment: I was trying to test the proposed approach and getting the below error:  ==> "message": "Unable to execute n1ql query due to error:{\"msg\":\"Invalid LIMIT value 5.\",\"code\":5030}"                                                                                 `     @Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} where #{#n1ql.filter} OFFSET $2 LIMIT $1")
    Flux<Company> findByIdLimitAndOffset(String limit, String offset);` Can somebody suggest what I am doing wrong here with limit=5&offset=0 values?

Comment: Limit and Offset must be integers